# I need to draw a Triangle in Java from Incenter and sides, ideas?

Tags: java, geometry

I am not so worried about how to interpret how to draw the triangles, but I have been trying to find how to find the indices for triangle knowing only the sides, and incenter of the triangle.

**Some sample triangle inputs:**

```
Side 1: 20
Side 2: 30
Side 3: 40
about x=100, y=400

Side 1: 20
Side 2: 40
Side 3: 50
about x=300, y=400
```

Myself, and a couple of other people, have been wracking our brains for the past 4 hours to no avail, so, any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your specification does not describe a unique triangle - what about its rotation around the centre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you first need to figure out is the positions of each corner. As you have the length of each side you could use [the law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)...

[image: law of cosines]

...to get the angle between *side 1 (a)* and *side 2 (b)*:

[image: angle]

The positions of the triangle corners are:

- a) [0, 0]
- b) [b, 0]
- c) [c * cos(angle), c * sin(angle)]

After this you have a triangle originating from the wrong place as you want them to be drawn in the center of the triangle. Calculating that center of an triangle could be done in [different ways](http://www.jimloy.com/geometry/centers.htm), but here is one really simple one:

```
centerX = (a.x + b.x + c.x) / 3
centerY = (a.y + b.y + c.y) / 3
```

You could then translate that point to the point of your choice!

---

Here is some code that does what you want:

```
static class Triangle {
    double a, b, c;

    public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public double aAngle() {
        return Math.acos(-(Math.pow(a, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2) - Math.pow(c, 2)) / (2 * b * c));
    }

    public Point[] triangle() {

        double angle = aAngle();

        Point[] p = new Point[3];

        p[0] = new Point(0, 0);
        p[1] = new Point((int) b, 0);
        p[2] = new Point((int) (Math.cos(angle) * c), (int) (Math.sin(angle) * c));

        Point center = new Point((p[0].x + p[1].x + p[2].x) / 3, 
                                 (p[0].y + p[1].y + p[2].y) / 3);

        for (Point a : p)
            a.translate(-center.x, -center.y);

        return p;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Triangle t = new Triangle(20, 30, 40);
    final Point translation = new Point(100, 400);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JComponent() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Point[] p = t.triangle();

            g.translate(translation.x, translation.y);

            for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
                g.drawLine(p[i].x, 
                           p[i].y, 
                           p[(i+1) % p.length].x, 
                           p[(i+1) % p.length].y);
        }
    });

    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `a.translate(-center.x, -center.y);`?

Comment: Big ups for the remedial math :-)

Comment: @eric Correct, fixed! Thanks!

Comment: Also `a*a - b*b - c*c` is a hell of a lot more readable than `Math.pow(a, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2) - Math.pow(c, 2)`

Comment: @dacwe and @eric: Thanks to you both. We were actually very close to what you suggested we try, but we could not find the theorem for what you used here and was our major stumbling block: `c) [c * cos(angle), c * sin(angle)]`. Does it have a name that you are aware of? I know its a derivative for the law of sines. Trig is absolutely one of my worst math subjects, so thanks for the help. also, as for basing the center off of the incenter here is good source, which I am sure you already knew: [Incenter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incenter.html)

Comment: @KJ6YET: Check out the [wikipedia page of Sine and especially the unit circle section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Relation_to_the_unit_circle). If you rotate a line of length `c` and with an angle of `a` x and y of that line behaves like `c * cos(a)` and `c * sin(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it without any trigonometric functions!**

Consider the horizonal and vertical components of the *b* and *c* edges (let *a* be horizontal). By definition:

> b<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + b<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup> = b<sup>2</sup>
>
> c<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + c<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup>

But also, due to being part of the triangle:

> b<sub>x</sub> + c<sub>x</sub> = a
>
> b<sub>y</sub> = c<sub>y</sub> = height

Substituting:

> b<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + b<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>
>       = b<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + h<sup>2</sup>
>       = b<sup>2</sup>
>
> c<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + c<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>
>       = (a - b<sub>x</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + h<sup>2</sup>
>       = (a<sup>2</sup> - 2ab<sub>x</sub>) + (b<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + h<sup>2</sup>)
>       = (a<sup>2</sup> - 2ab<sub>x</sub>) + b<sup>2</sup>
>       = c<sup>2</sup>

Now we can find b<sub>x</sub>:

> b<sub>x</sub> = (a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> - c<sup>2</sup>) / 2a

And using our first equation:

> b<sub>y</sub> = sqrt(1 - b<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup>)

---

In code:

```
static class Triangle {
    double a, b, c;

    public Triangle(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Point[] coords() {
        Point[] p = new Point[3];
        double bx = (a*a + b*b - c*c) / (2*a);

        p[0] = new Point(0, 0);
        p[1] = new Point(a, 0);
        p[2] = new Point(bx, Math.sqrt(b*b - bx*bx));

        Point center = new Point(
            (p[0].x + p[1].x + p[2].x) / 3, 
            (p[0].y + p[1].y + p[2].y) / 3
        );

        for (Point a : p)
            a.translate(-center.x, -center.y);

        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric. I would still like to know where dacwe got his version just because I can't seem to find it. I dug out my old trig book from years ago this morning and can't seem to find where that came from.

Comment: Simple - it's a point on a unit circle. The point at angle `a` from the x axis, distance `r` from the origin is at `[r cos a, r sin a]`.

Comment: I need to go back and refresh my trig... Thanks @Eric